# What is causing 'Parse file to resource error' when loading tsfile in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: file, apache-iotdb, iotdb

What may be why *parse file to resource error* when loading a `tsfile` in Apache IoTDB?

When I tried to load tsfile in Apache IoTDB using :

```
load '/data/henaniotdb/data/data/sequence/root.TY/0/0/1662621857867-7-0-2.tsfile'
```

an error occurred:

> Msg: 701: Parse file /data/henaniotdb/data/data/sequence/root.TY/0/0/1662621857867-7-0-2.tsfile to resource error

What may be the reason for this kind of error when loading?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems like the tsfile name is too long to load in Apache IoTDB. You can check the log record to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).